# CheckSum on SQL Server Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it a good idea to add checksum on each record in SQL Server (updated by application only) to prevent and check whether the record was updated manually using an external script? If not, what is the best approach for this?

Comment: Why would a checksum prevent that? The "external script" would just update the checksum as well. To stop unauthorised changes to data, implement security properly

Answer (score 0):

Use triggers to prevent changes (roll them back). Or use them to audit changes (log the changes into a seperate table).

```
-- Add trigger to prevent data changes 
CREATE TRIGGER [active].[myTriggerOfInfinitePower] ON [active].[mySpecialSparkleTable] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 
BEGIN 

  -- Detect inserts 
  IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (select * from deleted) 
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        RAISERROR ('inserts are not allowed on that table', 15, 1); 
        RETURN; 
    END 

  -- Detect deletes 
  IF EXISTS (select * from deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (select * from inserted) 
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        RAISERROR ('deletes are not allowed on that table', 15, 1); 
        RETURN; 
    END 

  -- Detect updates 
  IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND EXISTS (select * from deleted) 
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
        RAISERROR ('updates are not allowed on that table', 15, 1);  
        RETURN; 
    END 

END; 
GO
```

Source: [use triggers to prevent changes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5291/audit-and-prevent-unwanted-sql-server-table-changes/)

Regarding checksums:
Adding a checksum column (a) won't "prevent" a record change via SQL Script (etc.) and (b) someone running such a script could always update the checksum (in theory - unless you do some secret squirrel hashing).

Comment: Hi robnick, we are trying to detect whether a data was changed, we have considered the trigger as well but given that a personnel is knowledgeable enough, they can simply disable the trigger.

Comment: You're in a catch-22 situation. An authorised user is going to always be able to get-around whatever cleverness you put in place. Lock down all external user access and only allow direct access to the DB by a trusted DBA. Combine that with triggers, so that if a "rogue" program/application tries to change/delete, then its detected.

Comment: You might also want to post this question over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ which is probably a better source of solutions since this isn't strictly a programming issue. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thank you very much robnick!